# Build error in debug only

Tags: c#, asp.net

When I convert my solution to 64 bit then it builds fine in **Release** but in **Debug** it gives me these error's while building solution.

I already tried cleaning solution but no gain only pain.

> Error 1 Warning as Error: Assembly generation -- Referenced assembly
>   'my.project.abc.dll' targets a different processor solution.project1

and

> Error 2 Warning as Error: Reference to type
>   'System.Security.Authentication.ExtendedProtection.ChannelBinding'
>   claims it is defined in
>   'c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.dll', but it
>   could not be found c:\Documents and
>   Settings\Administrator\Desktop\System.Web.dll solution.project1

If problem is with dll's then why build successfully for release  and work in "**Any CPU**"

These are third party dlls and well tested.